# What is the html for color "Olive Green, Accent 3, Lighter 60%"?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I want to set the background color of an HTML `table` element to:

> "Olive Green, Accent 3, Lighter 60%"

But I can't seem to to find its color code. I have checked this site http://amalfaro-wrk.tiddlyspace.com/Interface.ColorSchemes but they only have the code for:

> "Olive Green, Accent 3, Lighter 80% which is #EBF1DE".

Does anyone know the equivalent color code for where the percentage for Lighter is 60%?

Comment: use `rgba(); CSS3 method`

Comment: @KheemaPandey Alpha is transparency. I think OP is looking for an opaque colour.

Comment: http://www.color-hex.com/color/ebf1de try this

Comment: That's a MS Office colour name isn't it? I don't have Office installed here but if you can post a screenshot of the colour you want, we can just colorpick it and tell you. Alternatively, you can colorpick it yourself with [many programs](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=windows%20colour%20picker)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The color named *"Olive Green, Accent 3, Lighter 60%"* is part of the Excel palette.

Taking a screenshot and picking the color code in a graphics program leads to: **#D8E4BC**

[image: Olive Green shades, Excel 2010]

Comment: I suspect this is almost certainly the answer the OP wants

Comment: @Joe How were you able to get the color codes for these?

Answer (score 1):

Well the colour *Olive Green* from [an off-shoot](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm) of the page you've linked to can be represented in hexadecimal as `#333300`. Using an online tool like [this one](http://www.hexcolortool.com/#333300) we can easily make it lighter or darker by a certain percentage. In this case, making it 60% Lighter results in the colour `#CCCC99`.

[image: Colour Chart]

Comment: For my information, how accurate is this? I believe, this is purely on how the user will choose light/more light, etc., but What is exactly "Olive Green" in `#` cannot be judged?

Comment: @NKL I used the Olive Green from the page OP linked to (or at least, [this page](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm), which the page OP linked to links to). It defines *Olive Green* in a `table` whose `td` element has the attribute `bgcolor="#333300"`.

Comment: guys lets leave the color choice for OP. its very hard to get exact  `hex` value.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - I agree, but my point is .. If Black is `#000000`, Red is `#FF0000`, so what is olive green in `#` is an assumption from what you have mentioned in your answer. It does not has exactness and that is obvious as not all colors have that and will vary upon user preferences.

Comment: @NKL as I said, I'm using the page OP linked to which defines Olive Green as `#333300`. Not much more I can do than that.